# Как сделать переход к следующему действию нажатием любой точки на экране

Tags: ipad, objective-c, ios, iphone

Для перехода к следующему событию мне необходимо нажать кнопку, а я хочу чтобы можно было нажать не кнопку а любую точку на экране, как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам следует посмотреть в сторону [UITapGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Добавляется предельно просто одним из двух способов:

1. Из кода

```
// где-нибудь во viewDidLoad
UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewTapped:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
```

также следует реализовать сам метод обработчик

```
- (void)viewTapped:(id)sender 
{
    // следующее действие
}
```

2. Interface Builder (более предпочтительный способ)

В левой панели среди кнопок, вьюх и контроллеров найдите UITapGestureRecognizer и перетащите его на вашу вьюху.

После этого нужно добавить обработку события на этот жест, также как вы это обычно делаете с обыкновенной кнопкой.

[image: InterfaceBuilder]

Answer (score 3):

добавить в .m файл

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //ваш код, который выполнится после тапа
}
```

Comment: Но для этого нужно отнаследоваться от вьюхи на которой нужно ловить тап.

Comment: Любой UIViewController имеет такой метод, добавлять UITapGestureRecognizer не обязательно. Как я понял, человек не хочет добавлять кнопку на свою вьюху, и хочет по тапу что-то делать.
Можно немного исправить:
добавить в .m файл вашего UIViewController.

Comment: @tragvar, да, вы правы, я ошибся.